# Autocomplete jQuery, apache php and sql search system load concerns

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, apache

I'm building a website with an autocomplete search field.

The technique I use is a quite simple approach containing jQuery, PHP (apache) and MySQL.
This is the jQuery snippet I use right now:

```
function initAutocompleteSearch() {
    var requestTime;
    var inputField = $("#searchstring");
    var input = '';
    inputField.keyup(function() {
        window.clearTimeout(requestTime);
        input = $(this).val();
        requestTime = setTimeout(function() {
            getSearchData(input);
        }, 500); 
    });
}

function getSearchData(input) {
    var params = 'term=' + input;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/json_search',
        data: params,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            var resultString = '';
            if(data.type === 'success') {
                $.each(data.entries, function(key, val) {
                    resultString += '<li>' + val + '</li>';
                });
            } else {
                resultString = data.message;
            }
            $('#search-results').html(resultString);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR)
        {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}
```

So after I get some input, I wait half a second and launch the request. On the server side the first thing I do, is check, sanitize and validate the search term. If it only contains numbers and alphabetical characters, I hand the term over to a search function, which queries a search index table which answers with some found item ids, which then get joined and so on.
As the search index is not too small (around 20 million entries and growing), I'm trying to calculate the load I put on my database. I'm quite sure I should use a separate database server for these queries at some time, but right now it seems to work fair enough.

The whole system is running on a i7-3930K Hexa-Core with 64GB RAM. I plan to move all the searching activity to a seperate machine with apache solr, but right now, I need to calculate the maximum more or less parallel search requests the server would be capable of if application and database run on the same system. Of course not exactly, but some numbers to work with would be great.

Comment: Increase the time to 1 sec from half a second, number will decrease to half :)

Comment: Yeah of course, but this is only stupid client code. You could write a programm to request example.com/ajax/json_search with the maximum speed and open connections your system allows. My question was, when I'm going to feel the load?